# HTTP methods other than doDelete method + java servlet?

Tags: servlets

I want to know if I can use any other http method (eg. get or post) instead of `doDelete` method to perform the same functionality as `doDelete`.

Comment: You have to override the `doDelete()` in your Servlet to achieve what you desire ! Same can be done through `GET` or `POST`, depending on your use-case ! Need more information on what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your quick response. I want to delete a file from server using OATS open script. But i can not use doDelete method as it's not available in OATs  script. So i was looking for another method if i can override for the same function. If i can use doGet method, could you please give me the example.

Answer (score 0):

A GET request is reputed idempotent, that is to say it should not modify the persistent data. And you should be able to repeat Get requests with obtaining same result (provided the datas have not been modified elsewhere ...).

So it would be better to use POST to delete data. You can either use a dedicated URL (eg : `/data/id/delete` or `/data/delete/id`) or use request params (URL = `/data` params = `action=delete&id=id`) or a mix of those 2 solutions.